# Alpaca form submission, stay on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am building a form with PHP and ALPCA (jquery,ajax). I am having trouble with file submitting and staying on the same page. I have tried the recommended techniques for doing as such with AJAX `event.preventDefault();`, also using hidden frame but with no success. My question is does the ALPACA package require a different method?

**FORM SECTION**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#form").alpaca({
            "schema": {
                    "title":"User Feedback",
                    "description":"What do you think about this Speaker?",
                    "type":"object",
                    "properties": {
                        "email": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "title":"Email",
                            "required":false
                        },
                        "feedback": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "title":"Feedback"
                        },
                        "ranking": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "title":"Ranking",
                            "enum":['It is Great', 'Not so cool', 'Very poor quality', 'I think there may be a Privacy or Copyright issue'],
                            "required":false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "options": {
                    "form":{
                        "attributes":{
                            "action":"FORM.php",
                            "method":"post"
                            "target":"hiddenFrame"
                        },
                        "buttons":{
                            "submit":{}
                        }
                    },
                    "helper": "What do you think about this Speaker?",
                    "fields": {
                        "email": {
                            "size": 20,
                            "placeholder": "email not nessasary"
                        },
                        "feedback" : {
                            "type": "textarea",
                            "name": "your_feedback",
                            "rows": 4,
                            "cols": 40,
                            "helper": ""
                        },
                        "ranking": {
                            "type": "select",
                            "helper": "",
                           "optionLabels": ["It is Great", "Not so cool", "Very poor quality", "I think there may be a Privacy or Copyright issue"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php

$file = "people.txt";
$feedback = $_REQUEST['feedback'];
$ranking = $_REQUEST['ranking'];
$email= $_REQUEST['email'];
$string = file_get_contents("/tmp/live-info");

$json = str_replace('***(', $callback, $string);
$json = rtrim($json, ')');

$json_a = json_decode($json, true);

$current_name = $json_a['current'][name];

$current_name .= "|$email|$ranking";

$feedback .= "|$current_name" .PHP_EOL;

file_put_contents($file, $feedback, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

If you want an alpaca form to submit solely trough ajax you can use something along these lines.

First, to make the submit button use ajax when clicked set its `click` property (i.e. `options.form.buttons.submit.click`) to something like:

```
function(){
    this.ajaxSubmit().done(function(){
        console.log('Saved');
    }).fail() {
        console.warn('Failed to save');
    });
}
```

Now, clicking the submit button will save the form with ajax and the user will remain on page. What's left is handling the standard submit. This can be done setting `postRender` (a root callback, see [documentation](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/callbacks.html)) to something along these lines:

```
function(control) {
    if (control.form) {
        control.form.registerSubmitHandler(function (e) {
        control.form.getButtonEl('submit').click();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Hope this still helps.